# Bypassing ASP.NET's One RUNAT SERVER FORM per page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, runatserver

ASP.NET restricts using more than 1 `runat="server"` form.

I have a **Master Page**, currently with no form.

I have many other pages, some with a form (Register.aspx - Login.aspx), some without a form.

I would like to add a **Logout button** in the master (After a user has logged in).

This is kind of normal, the **Logout button** should always be there.

But to use this **ASP Button Controller** I need to use a **form** in the Master Page.

Means, I will not be able to access other pages that has forms because I will receive an error.

I already have other ideas to bypass this.

1- Using **JQuery** to Load a **Handler** using **Ajax**, clear the Session.

2- Make the Logout a **link** which looks like a button, click on it to load another **.aspx page**, in the Page Load method, clear the Session, then redirect, sounds like the first one...

3- Make it a link which takes me to the same page (Default.aspx?logout=1) <- and check this **parameter** inside the Page Load method, if it's there, clear the Session.

Are these good approaches? is there any better?

Comment: I will go with the second approach, with redirecting to a page which clears session and all, but i don't consider this good enough,  any new approach will be appreciated.

Comment: You could create a form without `runat="server"` and then check for something like `if(Request.Form["LogoutButton"] == "Logout")`, but just putting a global server form in the master is almost always the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bypass it, just wrap the entire `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` inside the `form runat="server"` so you'll have the form on every page already.

In the master page

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainBodyContent"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Care to explain why you can't have the Form in your masterpage and remove all forms in those pages using that masterpage? That's the most common pattern in ASP.NET anyway.

If you for some reason can't do that, I would go with 2.